# a document path must be a non-empty string 'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart'

Tags: flutter, mobile, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to develop chat application. But I am getting error if I want to send a message to a chat. And I dont know where should I fix my error. Can someone help me and tell me what I did wrong and correct me somewhere?

P/s: im still new for chat development in flutter

[image: This is the error i got when i try to send message]

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    listScrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);

    groupChatId = '';
    readLocal();
}

readLocal() async {
    prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    id = prefs.getString('id');
    if (id != null && !id.isEmpty) {
      if (id.hashCode <= peerId.hashCode) {
        groupChatId = '$id-$peerId';
      } else {
        groupChatId = '$peerId-$id';
      }
      FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('User')
          .doc(id)
          .update({'chattingWith': peerId});

      setState(() {});
    }
    
    void onSendMessage(String content, int type) {
    if (content.trim() != '') {
      textEditingController.clear();

      var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Message')
          .doc(groupChatId)
          .collection(groupChatId)
          .doc(DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString());

      FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
        transaction.set(docRef, {
          'idFrom': id,
          'idTo': peerId,
          'timestamp': DateTime.now().millisecondsSinceEpoch.toString(),
          'content': content,
          'type': type
        });
      });
      listScrollController.animateTo(0.0,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.easeOut);
    } else {
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
          msg: 'Nothing to send',
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          textColor: Colors.white);
    }
}
```

Comment: bro i think your groupchat id coming null so make sure its not be null

Comment: how to make it not null? im sorry im dont know how to solve it

Comment: As @Muhammad Arbaz Zafar said, it seems that your `groupChatId` is the porblem. Can you please check its value when you call `FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection().doc()`?

Comment: i try to do what you tell, the message is save into database but the idfrom and idto is null

Comment: Where are you defining the `peerId`?

Comment: i am just declaring as String peerId;

Comment: Have you previously set the values of your `SharedPreferences.getInstance()` object, in order to retrieve them later (the `id`)? If you are just declaring the `peerId` variable, and you don't assign any value to it, you can not use it later with the `hashCode` property.

Comment: Sorry for asking, how to set values for the SharedPreferences.getInstance()? do i need to add the sharedpreferences object to the list of user before start chatting?

Answer (score 2):

That is because you are passing an empty value to the database. I had a similar problem where I was passing the last message to the database, and I was initializing it with "". Try putting something like a space " " instead.