# a document path must be a non-empty string-error

Tags: flutter

```
a document path must be a non-empty string
'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart':
Failed assertion: line 116 pos 14: 'path.isNotEmpty'
```

I'm getting above error in my code. don't know where to fix this. here you can find the full code of my conversaton.dart file. [ConversationScreen.dart](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1XbKrCuCWsOIfLj5rhyWXsLTduczzGnbS5o7KJHxvQkM/edit?usp=sharing)... also on the emulator it has display this error. does anyone know how to fix this.

[image: emulator error]

```
  sendMessage(){
    if (messageController.text.isNotEmpty){
      Map<String,String> messageMap ={
        "message": messageController.text,
        "sendBy" : Constants.myName
      };
      databaseMethods.addConversationMessages(widget.chatRoomId, messageMap);
      messageController.text = "";
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ChatMessageList() {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: chatMessagesStream,
    builder: (context, snapshot) {
     // check whether the doc is empty first
         print((snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs); 
         return ListView.builder(
           itemCount: (snapshot.data! as QuerySnapshot).docs.length,

             itemBuilder:(context, index){

             return MessageTile(snapshot.data!.docs[index]["message"],);
             });
    },
  );
}
```

Check this first

Also,

```
var docRef = FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Message')
           /// check if you have passed the correct id
          .doc(groupChatId)   
          .collection(groupChatId)
```

Similar issue : [a document path must be a non-empty string 'package:cloud_firestore/src/collection_reference.dart'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67767157/a-document-path-must-be-a-non-empty-string-packagecloud-firestore-src-collecti)

Comment: where I can find this docRef variable??

Comment: You are using firebase. So, search for `.doc(` globally in project.

Comment: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'QuerySnapshot<Object?>' in type cast<< im getting this error now